# Correct use of sharing a static 'Random' singleton instance?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static, singleton

**Question background:**

I currently have a couple of 'Random' number instances in my code - used in two classes -  where I need to append a randomly generated number to the name of some folders I am creating. Once the work - in this case mapping files to these new folders - is done they're immediately deleted.

**Code:**

I have two private static instances of the following code in each of the mentioned classes:

```
private static randomNo = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

**Singleton? Or two static instances?:**

So far I have not run into any duplication issues. I still feel that I should be developing a singleton to share a single static random number object instance over my whole solution.

I am using IoC (Unity) to create all of my classes and am not sure how I should go about handling sharing the static Random instance? Can I 'new' the singleton class up in each class that requires it? Or will this cause the static Random instance to reset? Do I need to create one singleton class and pass it between the classes requiring a randomly generated number?

I should mention I do have checks in place to ensure that when a new folder name is created with a random number appended to it, I ensure the name doesn't already exist.

Comment: The potential issue isn't quite clear to me. You talk about duplication. Do you mean that to different generators could generate the same number? One single generator could also generate the same number twice in a row.

Comment: @GolezTrol I guess what I would like to know is can I stick with two private static variables as I have now? Or is it best practice to implement a singleton? I am just wondering if I would need to pass a single Singleton instance between the classes?

Comment: You can pass a singleton along as well. The advantage is that your application doesn't rely heavily on the fact that it's a singleton. If you just call the singleton from everywhere in your application, it will be more work to refactor it. On the other hand, when will you need to change it, and how many calls are there going to be...

Comment: I must admit, I'm not sure how to return singletons from Unity, especially hiding the fact that it's a singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't strictly need to use a `Random` singleton throughout your application. Most of the time (including in this case) using more than one instance is a sign of preferring convenience over "theoretical correctness", but there are legitimate cases where different program components use different RNGs by design so that the behavior of each component over the lifetime of the program is deterministic.

If you want to move to a singleton instance you should use [`RegisterType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainer_methods%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) to instruct the container that it should satisfy all requests for a `Random` object with the same instance:

```
container.RegisterType<Random>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

This will not create a `Random` instance on the spot; instead, it will instruct the container that once a request for `Random` has been resolved, subsequent requests will be resolved with that same instance.

After that, it's just a matter of resolving the singleton instance with `container.Resolve<Random>()` or making the dependency visible to the container so that it automatically resolves and injects the RNG instance when you instruct it to resolve one of the RNG's users.

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason to mess care one-way-or-the other then it should make no difference if you have one or 10 RNG variables floating around your code. Afterall, they all produce random numbers with uniformly random distribution.

Do what's in the best interest of maintainability and you likely won't go astray